# Remove/Prevent .js file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iphone

Hi I am working with a webservice and I have to manipulate the design to make it look better. Recently I had to make it work on IPad. 
So my Problem is my edit's don't work in Iphone because the service adds if its a mobile device a viewport and an extra .js file. This is causing unwanted changes. So is there a way to prevent the system from loading / opening? I can use Javascript to do this. My recent trys was to get the "IPhone.js" and make it empty

```
var scriptElements = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var patt = /iPhone.js/g;
var sourceOfElement = "";
for (var i = 0; i < scriptElements.length; i++) {
  sourceOfElement = scriptElements[i].src;
  if (patt.test(sourceOfElement)) {
    scriptElements[i].src = "";
  };
```

This didn't really worked because the IPhone.js is loaded before I can "make it empty".

Another try was to remove the viewport, this also did't worked.

So anybody have any idea how to prevent the service from loading/executing the IPhone.js?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `iphone.js` to execute just add a return statement at the start of the `iphone.js` file if condition is matched

**iPhone.js**

```
if(YOUR_CONDITION_NOT_TO_EXECUTE_IPHONE_JS) return; //check for your condition and return
//Other iphone.js code
```

Comment: Then add the iphone.js dynamically as the second answer.

Answer (score 0):

can you add iphone.js via javascript not script tag? 
It will be something like this:

```
if (shouldILoad) {
        (function() {
            var myscript = document.createElement('script');
            myscript.type = 'text/javascript';
            myscript.src = ('iphone.js');
            var s = document.getElementById('myscript');
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(myscript, s);
        })();
    }
```